# Saml response sent to default reply URL under app registrations

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml, azure-authentication

I have a custom web app registered with azure. The reply URL is mentioned in the SSO settings and it was working fine. but last week we were not able to access the app we found that SAML response was being sent to loopback address URL (https://127.0.0.1:444/applications/default.aspx) which is default reply URL available under app registrations when we registered the app.Could not get any information from audit logs.

could you please let us know what could be the possible reason for SAML response being to Loopback address?

we haven't done any changes to reply URL. we checked with application team and updated the reply URL with new URL and it worked again.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, not a satisfying answer since I can't say what broke, but one of my apps started doing this today and I was able to fix it.  Basically it forgot/was ignoring your setting.

I had to go into the Enterprise Application, Single sign-on, then to the domains and URLs.  Change the reply URL to a dummy address (I copied the good reply url to relay state, but as long as you don't lose it you can put it anywhere).  I then tested and instead of going to https://127.0.0.1:444/applications/default.aspx, I went to the dummy reply address I put in.

Then I was able to go back, put the Reply URL back to the correct setting and we're back in business.

Answer (score 1):

We had this same problem today. On 4 of our Azure SSO apps.
All of our apps have two Reply URLs. But only 4 of them were down.

Users were seeing the "can't reach this page" error in the browser, with the ***https://127.0.0.1:444*** address.

[image]

We fixed by editing the Reply URLs on each app's App Registration.
We removed the https://127.0.0.1:444 entry.

Still not sure why only four of our SSO apps were affected. All others worked fine without being changed.